# Scrapy spider won't jump to next page

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm building a scaper with Scrapy for swedish ecommerce site Blocket.se.
It's scraping the first page as it should, but it won't jump the next.

The command for next url

```
response.xpath(u'//a[contains(text(), "Nästa")]/@href').extract()
```

outputs an "incomplete" link when I try it in Scrapy shell:

```
?q=cykel&cg=0&w=1&st=s&c=&ca=11&l=0&md=th&o=2
```

Does it have to be a "full" link to work?:

```
https://www.blocket.se/stockholm?q=cykel&cg=0&w=1&st=s&c=&ca=11&l=0&md=th&o=2
```

Starting-url: https://www.blocket.se/stockholm?q=cykel&cg=0&w=1&st=s&c=&ca=11&is=1&l=0&md=th

Full code:

```
import scrapy

class BlocketSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "blocket"
    start_urls = ["https://www.blocket.se/stockholm?q=cykel&cg=0&w=1&st=s&c=&ca=11&is=1&l=0&md=th"]

    def parse(self, response):
        urls = response.css("h1.media-heading > a::attr(href)").extract()
        for url in urls:
            url = response.urljoin(url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_details)


        #follow pagination links
        next_page_url = response.xpath(u'//a[contains(text(), "Nästa")]/@href').extract()
        if next_page_url:
            next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page_url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_details(self, response):
        yield {
        "Objekt": response.css("h1.h3::text").extract(),
        "Säljare":response.css("li.mrl > strong > a::text").extract(),
        "Uppladdad": response.css("li.mrl > time::text").extract(),
        "Pris": response.css("div.h3::text").extract(),
        "Område": response.css("span.area_label::text").extract(),
        "Bild-URL": response.css("div.item > img::attr(src)").extract(),
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, scrapy needs the full URL, usually. But you can keep using `urljoin()` or using the `response.follow()` method:

```
next_page_url = response.xpath(u'//a[contains(text(), "Nästa")]/@href').extract()
if next_page_url:
    yield response.follow(url=next_page_url, callback=self.parse)
```

More about this in [Scrapy Tutorial](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#a-shortcut-for-creating-requests).